# How to extract a value from an XML string?

Tags: python, json, xml

This below line returns a json result

```
json['@Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.fetchxmlpagingcookie']
```

Output appears as a string

```
'<cookie pagenumber="2" pagingcookie="%2520page%253d%25221" istracking="False" />'
```

I want to extract the pagingcookie value.
Expected output

```
%2520page%253d%25221
```

How can I get this?

Answer (score 0):

I would probably just extract it with a regex... but its probably more appropriate to use the xml library..

```
import re
s = '<cookie pagenumber="2" pagingcookie="%2520page%253d%25221" istracking="False" />'
print(re.search('pagingcookie="([^"]+)"',s).group(1))
```

to use xml

```
import xml
#same s as above
el = xml.dom.minidom.parseString(s).documentElement
print(el.getAttribute("pagingcookie"))
```

Comment: Thanks, which xml library can I use?

Comment: addressed in edit to answer